# Anyway to make this sorting algorithm more efficient/shorter C++

Tags: c++, sorting, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

```
// Number Sorting Algorithm - Trey Taylor 2014
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
    int main() {
        int numbersort [] = {200, 85, 63, 4}
        cout << "The numbers scrambled are: ";
        cout << numbersort[0] << ", ";
        cout << numbersort[1] << ", ";
        cout << numbersort[2] << ", ";
        cout << numbersort[3] << ", " << endl;
        firstlast:
        if (numbersort[0] > numbersort[1]) {
            int temp = 0;
            temp = numbersort[0];
            numbersort[0] = numbersort[1];
            numbersort[1] = temp;
        }
            if (numbersort[1] > numbersort[2]) {
                int temp = 0;
                temp = numbersort[1];
                numbersort[1] = numbersort[2];
                numbersort[2] = temp;
            }
                if (numbersort[2] > numbersort[3]) {
                    int temp = 0;
                    temp = numbersort[2];
                    numbersort[2] = numbersort [3];
                    numbersort[3] = temp;
                }
                        while (numbersort[0] > numbersort[1]) {
                        goto firstlast;
                }
        cout << "The numbers unscrambled are: ";
        cout << numbersort[0] << ", ";
        cout << numbersort[1] << ", ";
        cout << numbersort[2] << ", ";
        cout << numbersort[3] << ", ";
}
```

Does anybody know if there is a way to use a for or while loop to rearrange the numbers in the array into ascending order from left to right rather than just using 3 if statements

Comment: This seems to belong to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The shortest solution is to call [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).  See the link for an example.

Comment: If you want someone to review your code you should ask on [codereview.se]

Comment: Use `std::swap`.  Factor unused variables out of loops.

Comment: And the way you are using `while` and `goto` ... well, there is a special construction called `do...while` for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use std::sort or bubble sort algorithm([link how it works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)). Algorithm checks is current number in loop bigger from next one. If it is change those numbers in array. At the end you get the biggest number on the end of array and smallest at beggining of array.

```
int main()
{
    int numbersort[] = { 200, 85, 63, 4 };
    int temp = 0;
    // This loop sorts all numbers in the array
    for (int z = 0; z < 4; ++z)
    {
        // This loop sorts only one number to the end
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        {
            if (numbersort[i] > numbersort[i + 1])
            {
                temp = numbersort[i];
                numbersort[i] = numbersort[i + 1];
                numbersort[i + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Sorted numbers" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        cout << numbersort[i] << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
i = 0;
while (i < (sizeof(numbersort)/sizeof(numbersort[0])) - 1)
{
  if (numbersort[i] >= numbersort[i + 1])
  {
    std::swap(numbersort[i], numbersort[i + 1]);
    i = 0;
  }
  else
  {
    ++i;
  }
}
```